# Solution to manage a rental property's bookings across multiple booking platforms

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Morning/afternoon/evening all,

I am building a website for a rental property in France and the client wants to be able to use a single solution to manage bookings across the following platforms: Booking.com, AirBNB, Abritel (French) and Gites de France. Ideally, with the possibility of integrating TripAdvisor later.

So, when the centralised platform is updated, it updates across all the other platforms automatically. And when a booking is made, it feeds through to the centralised system.

I am highly doubtful that this one-shop solution exists but thought I would ask anyway. If it doesn't exist, would a bespoke solution be possible? Any other suggestions welcome.

Thank you

EDIT: I have learned that websites such as AirBnb can sync with iCal and Google Calendar. I wonder if this could be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

its is very possible provided the third party platforms have services that can be called for data exchange..... first check for the services exposed by those platforms and how to consume them.